# Do I make hundreds of Kafka brokers, or do I make a single super broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

I am working on setting up kafka and debezium to connect to a bunch of MySQL databases, for sake of conversation around 300

This is my first time working with Kafka so I was wondering what is the recommended way to go about things, set up an individual broker for each database, or set up a single broker with thousands of topics

It feels like it would be far easier in my case to manage individual brokers, is there a soft/hard limit in terms of how many brokers Zookeeper could manage?

Alternatively are there ways to manage/organize topics inside of a broker?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one Kafka cluster. You do not need one broker in the cluster per table. debezium would make one (or more) topics per table, in one Kafka cluster

Number of brokers depends on your data at rest, including a default of 7 days of retention, and including the fact that Kafka will replicate that data if setup that way (recommended), plus some overhead...

So, you'll need to sum up the table sizes, then sum up how much data is written per week, then provision storage from there. For example, one broker could have 24 attached volumes. Use 4TB disks, you'll get only 86TB total storage (excluding the OS). A 3 node cluster is recommended, so that's then 256TB of storage, and so on.

5 Zookeepers is recommended, but Kafka doesn't need zookeeper anymore

Then Debezium should run separately from the brokers. You can also run a cluster of those, but there's no real benchmarks for when to space up or out, as it depends on your actual tables